# How to manually set which version 'libstdc++.so.6' used instead of using the latest one?

Tags: c++, gcc, libstdc++

I got an error on my server.

> version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found

After I some investigation I found that 'libstdc++.so.6' version used when build the app on my local computer is much advanced than on server. So I got that error because that version is not available on server. From what I read, I can fixed that by upgrade 'libstdc++.so.6' on server to the latest one but I can't do that because the restricted acces. 
Is there any way to downgrade or make my local use older version as default?

Comment: Search about `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, etc.

Comment: @underscore_d thanks for the suggestion, but the path is correct.

Comment: [`LD_LIBRARY_PATH` considered harmful](https://gms.tf/ld_library_path-considered-harmful.html), there are better ways.

Comment: @d_w My point was not to check that your usual system libs were already specified there, but that you would need to add something there (or somewhere better) to make it prefer your downgraded version by default.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin Thanks! That may be useful for me too.

Answer (score 1):

When linking your application specify `-Wl,-rpath=$ORIGIN` to make it search for shared libraries in the folder where the executable is. Then copy `libstdc++.so.6` and other application dependencies (find them with `ldd`) into your application folder and distribute that folder. See [`man ld.so`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ld.so.8.html), section about `$ORIGIN`.